# send a parameter to javascript from cs function by out

Tags: javascript, out

Is it possible to return a parameter from c# function to javascript using out declare 
(for the parameter) ? 
Please add code example to your answer.

Comment: What happened when _you_ tried it?

Comment: Well i guess i dont know how to write the code right 
this what i wrote in c# : 
public string Hierarchy(string query,out int t)
        {
            t = 1;

         
        }

Comment: JavaScript running in the browser can't directly call C# functions running on the web server. You can make a request and have a response returned, but that's not the same thing and you wouldn't return the value via a function parameter like that.

Comment: Well i guess i dont know how to write the code right 
this what i wrote in c# : 
public string Hierarchy(string query,out int t)
        {
            t = 1;
            return "answer";
         }
javascript
 function search(query) {     
              Ajax.Call({
            method: "Hierarchy",
            parameters: [query,t]
        });

the t in javascript is undefined....
not sure at all.. need some guide

Comment: 't' would be the response, you don't have to pass t, post the ajax code and c# code of that method(it is webmethod?) in the question